# how can I select the below value with css selector

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have to select the height dropdown which is in the form of 4' 3". I am using the below css selector but it is not showing me any element in inspect element section.

Below is what I am using

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li[id$='4' 3']"));
```

Below is the HTML for this.

```html
<li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-height-fb-result-76nx-4' 3" role="option" aria-selected="false" data-select2-id="select2-height-fb-result-76nx-4' 3">4' 3"</li>
```

i>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
li[id$="4' 5"]
```

- this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This Selector is working for me.

```
li[id$=\"4\' 3\"]
```

So the single quote after 4 is acting as a closing brace so I tried to escape the locator braces